# Update Datagridview values with trim() values

Tags: datagridview, null, trim

I want to update datagridview values with trim values .
but i think the null value in datagridview makes ERROR .

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

Could you please help .
Thank you .

Comment: If `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` is `null`, then, `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` is going to fail with a null value exception. I suggest you check to make sure `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` is NOT `null` before attempting to call the `ToString()` method. `if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value != null) { …)`

Comment: thank you .work fine .